# Pycharm (@property) and (@x.setter) autogeneration

Tags: python, pycharm

I wonder whether there is some way of using Pycharm to automatically generate getter(@property) or setter for all my variables in a class.

If there is a way, can someone point it out ?

---

thanks! Actually I meant to generate (@property)  and (@x.setter) automatically.

Comment: If there is, there shouldn't be. You should only be using getters and setters when you actually need them.

Comment: In python you don't need to use getters and setters to keep your API safe.

Comment: Why not just make a snippet?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There isn't a way to do so. You can extract certain parts of code, but you cannot have pycharm generate getters and setters for you. There is no need either, since all variables are public, and the `_var` values, even though are treated as private variables can be altered as well.

EDIT (Change in question):

If you want to write less code when making getters and setters, then just use the `props` or the `propsd`snippet in PyCharm.

Comment: you can still hide some variable using Obj.__x, right ?

Comment: You can hide the attribute with a leading `__`, but you can't protect access to it. Just use one(!) leading underscore if you want to make clear that the attribute is for internal use only.

Comment: @Matthias Thats what I mean, you can always access stuff in Python. Everything is public.

Comment: code like http://pastebin.com/pg85f6KY gives  
AttributeError: p instance has no attribute '__h'. I think that means you can not access variable starting with __.

Comment: @Alex Gao: No, that just menas that you have to consider name mangling. Use `print b_1._p__h` and you'll get the data.

Comment: `prop` stands for `@property`, while `s` is for `setter` and `d` for `deleter`. thus making `propsd`.

Answer (score 9):

Just because Python doesn't enforce private members doesn't mean you have to do without them. But be warned that getters and setters are function calls and are much slower than direct member access.

PyCharm doesn't offer a menu to create properties for all your private members but it has a live template for it: within your class (indentation must be correct) type prop and press enter. A stub of your read only property will appear.

I adopted my live template to easily generate a getter like property:
Open Settings (Ctrl+Alt+S) -> Editor -> Live Templates -> Python -> prop

```
@property
def $NAME$(self):
    return self.__$NAME$
```

The same for live template `props` for read write access:

```
@property
def $NAME$(self) -> $TYPE$:
    return self.__$NAME$

@$NAME$.setter
def $NAME$(self, $NAME$: $TYPE$):
    self.__$NAME$ = $NAME$
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [a PyCharm Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/20946-python-getters-and-setters) that can generate getters and setters. It uses PyCharm's live templates to generate them and automatically selects private variables. Not very pretty, but it gets the job done.

As others have said, Python usually lets variables be public, but there is always a time and a place.

Comment: It works for some file but not for other *.py. Not much log to debug.

Comment: https://github.com/CJCrafter/PythonGettersAndSetters

It is open source if you want to check it out, but I'm not sure how to debug that issue, I would need more information on the failing cases.